# One time initialisation of a variable in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, ios6, initialization, cocos2d-x

I am working on one game in cocos2d-x (iOS). There I have created few scenes and did transitions in between those scenes. During each transition init() of each scene(layer) is called (Also constructor is called each time before init()). My question is, How can I make ONLY ONE time initialisation of my variable inside this init() or constructor, even when init() is called each time? Or any OTHER alternative solution for the same?

```
  CCUserDefault::sharedUserDefault()->setBoolForKey("firstTimeInit", false);

    bool firstTimeInit = CCUserDefault::sharedUserDefault()->getBoolForKey("firstTimeInit");

    if (!firstTimeInit)
    {

     for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
       char szName[22] = {0};
       sprintf(szName, "Rank%i", i);

       CCUserDefault::sharedUserDefault()->setIntegerForKey(szName,0);
       CCUserDefault::sharedUserDefault()->flush();

       int score = CCUserDefault::sharedUserDefault()->getIntegerForKey(szName);
       vScore.push_back(score);
     }
 CCUserDefault::sharedUserDefault()->setBoolForKey("firstTimeInit",true); }
```

I wrote this code inside init() method.. and I want that firstTimeInit which I made false, initialise only once.

EDIT #####

In cocos2d-x for every transition init() method is called that is why every time our initialisation takes place. Also I want this one time initialisation even after I quit my game and rerun. I tried it by using CCUserDefault's setBoolForKey() but in vain,as it is also in init().

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you are after

```
bool val = cocos2d::CCUserDefault::sharedUserDefault()->getBoolForKey("initialized");

if (val != true){
    cocos2d::CCUserDefault::sharedUserDefault()->setBoolForKey("initialized", true);
    cocos2d::CCLog(" initializing value ");
}
```

Comment: KJS, Thanks for the reply. I already tried this but output was not upto my expectation. I want to initialise variable ONLY ONCE.

Comment: i don't see the problem here. if you have that static class variable, code inside that if-clause is run only once, and you can init your variable there. It will be only executed on the first call of the init, not  any other call after that.

Comment: Yes it is..the solution you said doesn't work for my requirement..static variable maintains it's state till programme lasts..What I want is to maintain the state of my variable even after I close my programme and rerun it. I hope now you understood my problem why I said only once.

Answer (score 0):

currently whats happening :-

1>game starts you put firstTimeInit=false, which makes the if condition true;

2>then you assign firstTimeInit=true in the end.

3> you quit and game starts again and runs step 1 ,which will override present value in firstTimeInit from  true to false,again making the if condition true so you need to remove first statement

`CCUserDefault::sharedUserDefault()->setBoolForKey("firstTimeInit", false)`;

so that once the key is set to true it is never set to false;

Assumption:But I am assuming if a boolean key is not present then getting its value always returns false. Checked several times , and it returned false.